# How to change json jackson format for highcharts json

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, highcharts, jackson

I use Spring and the Jackson jackson-mapper-asl.

In my response i get this format back:

```
[{"temperature":8.0,"date":1393455600000},{"temperature":7.6,"date":1393456200000}]
```

but what i actually need is a different format like this:

```
[[1147651200000,8.0],[1147737600000,7.6]]
```

How does that work ? I need that format, because i want it to include to highcharts

Data Class:

```
package com.meteomatics.antigap.model;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonPropertyOrder;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ArrayNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

@JsonPropertyOrder({"temperature","date"})
public class Data {

    public DateTime dateTime;
    public Double temperature;




    public Data(DateTime dateTime, Double temperature){
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public DateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    @JsonProperty("date")
    public long getDateTimeAsUnixTimestamp() {
        return dateTime.getMillis();
    }
    public void setDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }


    public Double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(Double temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a s*load of annotations, make your class implement `JsonSerializable` and write a custom deserializer.

Here is code using Jackson 2.2.x; 1.9.x should not be very different.

First, the `Data` class (note: it should really be `final`, its members `private` and have no setters if you can afford that):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializable;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeSerializer;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import java.io.IOException;

@JsonDeserialize(using = DataDeserializer.class)
public class Data
    implements JsonSerializable
{
    public DateTime dateTime;
    public Double temperature;

    public Data(DateTime dateTime, Double temperature){
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public DateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public long getDateTimeAsUnixTimestamp() {
        return dateTime.getMillis();
    }
    public void setDateTime(DateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }


    public Double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(Double temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(final JsonGenerator jgen,
        final SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        jgen.writeStartArray();
        jgen.writeNumber(temperature);
        jgen.writeNumber(dateTime.getMillis());
        jgen.writeEndArray();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(final JsonGenerator jgen,
        final SerializerProvider provider, final TypeSerializer typeSer)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        typeSer.writeTypePrefixForArray(this, jgen);
        serialize(jgen, provider);
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffixForArray(this, jgen);
    }
}
```

Then the `DataDeserializer` class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import java.io.IOException;

public final class DataDeserializer
    extends StdDeserializer<Data>
{
    public DataDeserializer(final Class<?> vc)
    {
        super(vc);
    }

    public DataDeserializer(final JavaType valueType)
    {
        super(valueType);
    }

    @Override
    public Data deserialize(final JsonParser jp,
        final DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        final JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
        if (!node.isArray() || node.size() != 2)
            throw new JsonMappingException("was expecting array of two elements");

        final double temperature;
        DateTime dateTime;

        JsonNode element;
        element = node.get(0);
        if (!element.isFloatingPointNumber())
            throw new JsonMappingException("was expecting a double");

        temperature = element.doubleValue();

        element = node.get(1);
        if (!(element.isIntegralNumber() && element.canConvertToLong()))
            throw new JsonMappingException("was expecting a long");

        dateTime = new DateTime(element.longValue());
        return new Data(dateTime, temperature);
    }
}
```

Comment: how should i include that, all i do is that:
CSVReader<Data> csvDataReader = 
    new CSVReaderBuilder<Data>(reader)
     .strategy(new CSVStrategy(',','"','#',true,true))
     .entryParser(new CSVListEntryParser())
     .build();
  List<Data> listDatas = csvDataReader.readAll();

Comment: I see no Jackson code here... Is that your `Data` class which you serialize?

Comment: OK, please include the code of your `Data` class. The solution is there.

Comment: my data class looks like this:


@JsonPropertyOrder({"temperature","date"})
public class Data {
 
 public DateTime dateTime;
 public Double temperature;

 public Data(DateTime dateTime, Double temperature){
  this.dateTime = dateTime;
  this.temperature = temperature;
 }
 
 @JsonIgnore
 public DateTime getDateTime() {
  return dateTime;
 }

 @JsonProperty("date")
 public long getDateTimeAsUnixTimestamp() {
  return dateTime.getMillis();
 }
 public Double getTemperature() {
  return temperature;
 }
}

Comment: Please add this code to your question, not in a comment

Comment: If got aqn error on line1 in my dataclass :
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;

Comment: Error: The declared Pagacke "" does not match the expected packege

Comment: You don't need this import. Also, as I said, this is Jackson 2.2.x; suppress the import lines and use your IDE to import the correct ones. Or just use Jackson 2.2.X...

Comment: Well, add the package declaration on top

Comment: so if i delete all imports, i am not able to include the imports via IDE

Comment: Thank you, and how can i add the name like this:
[[temperature:8.0,date:1393455600000]] and how can i change the two parameters, that i get date first ?

Comment: You can't do the first, since that wouldn't be a JSON array anymore; as to changing the order of the two parameters, it should be quite easy to do by yourself by modifying the code of the `serialize()` method of `Data` and `deserialize()` method of `DataDeserializer`.